# Border radius html table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been trying to apply some rounded corners to a table of mine, but I just can't seem to get it right. My table is being collapsed, once the `<thead>`is clicked on. The `<thead>`need to only have top rounded corners, while the last `<tr>` element needs to only have bottom rounded corners. I'm using bootstrap as a framework.

Currently my design look like this:

[image: Current header]

[image: Current last element]

I want my `<head>` to look like this:

[image]

while the last element still have bottom rounded corners.

table.html

```
<table align="center" class="table table-curved" id="nextTeamTable">
    <thead data-parent="#bodyContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tbodyCollapse">
        <tr>
            <th>HeadTitle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="collapse" id="tbodyCollapse">
        <tr>
            <td>Body1</td>
            <td>Body2</td>
            <td>Body3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

table.css

```
.table-curved {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.table-curved tr:last-child td
{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;    
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;   
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**EDIT** - Try this: Put `overflow:hidden` on the `.tabled-curved` with the `border-radius: 25px;`. Then just Remove the rest of the border-radius CSS

Comment: Here's your code...with Bootstrap CSS. But more styling is required. Add whats missing, update, and I'll take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8013/

Comment: OMG... thanks so much Mike... where does it say that or do you know why that has to be that way in order for it to work?